# updatepanel loads whole page inside a iframe

Tags: .net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a page that shows inside an iframe. The iframe uses an UpdatePanel Ajax control to update a form inside it. However the whole page refreshes in IE although Firefox is fine. The validators dont wotk either.  My code (with Ajax) works outside the iframe.  What's happening? Thanks for your help. My code is:

container page:

```
  <IFRAME id="frame1" width="600px" frameborder="0" height="390px" src="http://www.site.ac. uk/page.aspx" runat="server"></IFRAME>
```

page.aspx:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="results"> 
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<h3>Enter amount</h3>
   <span>$ <asp:TextBox CssClass="text" ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></span><br />


   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="button" onClick="Button1_click" Text="Calculate" />
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="" ValidationExpression="^\d+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


  <asp:UpdatePanel id="results" runat="server">
   <Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>

  <ContentTemplate>
   <div class="amount"> 
   <h3>Amount</h3>
    <span>$ <asp:TextBox CssClass="text" ID="TextBox5" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox> </span><br />
 </div>


<h3>Total value:</h3>
 <span>$ <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" CssClass="text" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox> </span>

  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </div>

     </form>
```

page.aspx.vb

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox5.Text = (TextBox1.Text * 0.333333).ToString("F2")
    TextBox6.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox5.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Validator componant doesn't work inside the update panel use asp.net ajax-toolkit extension and use ValidatorCalloutExtender to control and validate. it works properly
[Look at this video in Asp.net](http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-validatorcallout-extender)